# Azure Site Recovery - generate Managed Service Identity

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azure-site-recovery

When testing ASR, the ASR VM's don't get a managed service identity.
Is there a best practise to deal with this scenario - including assigning permissions to the MSI, in such an event?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not possible to replicate, managed identities for Azure resources is a feature of Azure Active Directory. Each of the Azure services that support managed identities for Azure resources are subject to their own timeline. It means a DR is not a VM, it only exist a hard disk during replication.

What you can try to do, not sure it is going to work (never done before), you can try to create a postscript after a failover ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-create-recovery-plans)) and then configure your managed identities using PowerShell ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-powershell-windows-vm))

Answer (score -1):

Site Recovery supports managed identities for its Azure resources. Instead of creating service principals to access other resources, use managed identities with Site Recovery. Site Recovery can natively authenticate to the Azure services and resources that support Azure AD authentication. It authenticates through a predefined access grant rule without using credentials that are hardcoded in source code or configuration files.Azure-managed